# How can I get a key name (in a hash) by using its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I understand this is a little unorthodox.

Lets say I have this hash.

```
 someHash = {
    'item1' => '5',
    'item2' => '7',
    'item3' => '45',
    'item4' => '09'
}
```

Using native js, or prototype or Jquery -- is there a method that will enable me to get the "key name" by just having the value?

I don't want all the keys, just the one that matches my value. Sorta of a like a map in reverse?

I am getting a return from the db which I get a "value" and I have to match that value with some js hash on the front end.

So the app hands me "45"... Is there a way to use js (prototype or jquery) to then get the key "item3"?

Comment: You'll have to iterate over every single key/value pair and return the first key that contains your value.

Comment: Hashes don't work that way. They provide efficient lookup of the key to get the value. The other way around requires iteration of (possibly) every single key until you find the matching value. Just reverse your definition of key and value.

Comment: For normal arrays, you can use `.indexOf`, but you're talking about looping through object elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the **keys** which map to a given value you'll need to search the object properties.  For example

```
function getKeysForValue(obj, value) {
  var all = [];
  for (var name in obj) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty(name) && obj[name] === value) {
      all.push(name);
    }
  }
  return all;
}
```

Comment: What if the value is an array? like {a : ['b','c','d']}

Answer (score 5):

Using underscore.js:

```
_.invert(someHash)[value]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct method but you can try something like this.

```
var key;
$.each(someHash, function(key, val){
    if(val == 'valToCompare'){
        key = key;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `break` doesn't work because you don't have an actual loop. You need to `return false`.

Comment: Is jQuery really necessary here?

Comment: @Blender - It is not required but you can use any way to loop through if performance is not the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Without uniqueness you can get the first:

```
var hash = {item1: 0, item2: 1},
    value = 1,
    key;
for(var i in hash)
{
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(i) && hash[i] === value) {
        key = i;
        break;
    }
}
key; // item2
```

`hasOwnProperty` ensures that hash has the property not a prototype.

`break` stops the loop once a key is found.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a native answer, but you could write your own:

```
var someHash = {
  'item1' : '5',
  'item2' : '7',
  'item3' : '45',
  'item4' : '09'
};

function getKeyByValue(hash, value) {
  var key;
  for(key in hash) {
    if (hash[key] == value) return key;
  }
}

alert(getKeyByValue(someHash, '7'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`array_flip`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_flip:317) could help you. This makes a new array where the keys are the values and vice versa. Then, just look for the key in that new array, and the resulting value is the key in the original array you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the object.

```
function findInObj(obj, needle)
    for(var x in obj){
      if(obj.x==needle) return x;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow. the answers come fast on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Since more than one property in an object can have the same value,
you could return an array of the property names that match the value.

```
var someHash={
    'item1':'5',
    'item2':'7',
    'item3':'45',
    'item4':'09',
    'item5':'7'
}
function hasAny(what){
    var names= [];
    for(var p in this){
        if(this[p]=== what) names.push(p);
    }
    return names;
}
```

**hasAny.call(someHash, '7');**

/*  returned value: (Array)
item2,item5
*/